# How to add item transform to VS2012 .proj msbuild file

Tags: pdf, msbuild, docx

Based off this answer [describing an item transform to convert image files from jpg to png](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3447585/149060), I made an item transform that converts .docx file to .pdf.  When I call it from my projectname.proj build file I get this error message:

```
Error   1   The condition " '%(Extension)' == '.docx' " on the
"WordToPdf" target has a reference to item metadata. References to item 
metadata are not allowed in target conditions unless they are part of an item
transform. [project path]\.build\WordToPdf.Tasks.target 7   9
```

How can I make this work?

Here's my target:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
      <!-- $Id$ -->
      <Target Name="WordToPdf"
            Inputs="@(Content)"
            Outputs="@(Content -> '%(RootDir)%(Directory)%(Filename).pdf' )"
            Condition=" '%(Extension)' == '.docx' ">
        <ItemGroup>
          <Sublist Include="@(Content)" Condition=" '%(Extension)' == '.docx' " />
        </ItemGroup>
        <PropertyGroup>
          <PowerShellExe Condition=" '$(PowerShellExe)'=='' ">%WINDIR%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe</PowerShellExe>
          <ScriptLocation Condition=" '$(ScriptLocation)'=='' ">.\WordToPdf.ps1</ScriptLocation>
        </PropertyGroup>

        <Exec Command="$(PowerShellExe) -NonInteractive -executionpolicy Unrestricted -command &quot;&amp; {&amp;&apos;$(ScriptLocation)&apos; -WordFilename &apos;/Input:%(Sublist.FullPath)&apos; }&quot;" />

        <Content Remove="@(Sublist)" />
        <Content Include="@(Sublist -> '%(RootDir)%(Directory)%(Filename).pdf' )" />
      </Target>
    </Project>
```

And call it from my projectname.proj file from the BeforeBuild target, as follows:

```
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildTasksPath)\WordToPdf.Tasks.target" />

  ....

  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <CallTarget Targets="WordToPdf" />
  </Target>
```

**Update**

There was a bit more wrong with this target beyond just the workaround to get the transform to work.  For future reference, here's the final working code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <!-- $Id$ -->
  <Target Name="WordToPdf"
      Inputs="@(ContentFiltered)"
      Outputs="@(ContentFiltered -> '%(RootDir)%(Directory)%(Filename).pdf' )"
      DependsOnTargets="FilterContent">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <PowerShellExe Condition=" '$(PowerShellExe)'=='' ">%WINDIR%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe</PowerShellExe>
      <ScriptLocation Condition=" '$(ScriptLocation)'=='' ">.\WordToPdf.ps1</ScriptLocation>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Exec Command="$(PowerShellExe) -NonInteractive -executionpolicy Unrestricted -command &quot;&amp; {&amp;&apos;$(ScriptLocation)&apos; -WordFilename &apos;%(ContentFiltered.FullPath)&apos; }&quot;" />

    <ItemGroup>
      <Content Remove="@(ContentFiltered)" />
      <Content Include="@(ContentFiltered -> '%(RootDir)%(Directory)%(Filename).pdf' )" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
  <!-- New target to pre-filter list -->
  <Target Name="FilterContent">
    <ItemGroup>
      <ContentFiltered Include="@(Content)" Condition="'%(Extension)' == '.docx'" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>

</Project>
```

And, for anyone who got here searching for a "msbuild word to pdf item transform" 
here's my powershell script:

```
Param(
  [string]$WordFilename
)
$Word = New-Object -comobject Word.Application
$Doc=$Word.Documents.Open($WordFilename)
$Doc.saveas([ref](($WordFilename).replace("docx","pdf")), [ref]17)
$Doc.close()
```

Add the .docx file to your project, as content - copy if newer, and the pdf file will be created if the docx file is newer, and then the pdf file is copied to its output location.

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing `WordToPdf.Tasks.target`

Comment: @KMoraz the target is the first code block after the error message.  That's the entire contents of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can workaround it by creating separate target, which pre-filters items based on your condition - actually, creates new list.

Here is sample - notice new `DependsOnTargets` tag and changed `ContentFiltered` name:

```
  <Target Name="WordToPdf"
        Inputs="@(ContentFiltered)"
        Outputs="@(ContentFiltered -> '%(RootDir)%(Directory)%(Filename).pdf' )"
        DependsOnTargets="FilterContent">
    <!-- 
      ...
      your actual target body here 
      ...
      -->
  </Target>

  <!-- New target to pre-filter list -->
  <Target Name="FilterContent">
    <ItemGroup>
      <ContentFiltered Include="@(Content)" Condition="'%(Extension)' == '.docx'" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

Comment: That did the trick - after I also fixed the missing ItemGroup element.  I updated my question with the final working code.  You call it a 'workaround' - was this a bug, then?