# Msbuild- 'DependsOnTargets' that contain condition

Tags: msbuild

I tried to have a condition on a `Target` tag, but resulted with the error:
`target has a reference to item metadata. References
to item metadata are not allowed in target conditions unless they are part of an item transform.`

So i found this work around:
[How to add item transform to VS2012 .proj msbuild file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16202062/how-to-add-item-transform-to-vs2012-proj-msbuild-file)
and tried to implement it, but i can't figure up what i am doing wrong because it's not working as expected.

```
<CallTarget Targets="CopyOldWebConfigJs" /> 

<Target Name="CopyOldWebConfigJs" 
            Inputs="@(ContentFiltered)" 
            Outputs="%(Identity).Dummy" 
            DependsOnTargets="webConfigJsCase">

        <Message Text="web.config.js Case" />
</Target>

    <!-- New target to pre-filter list -->
<Target Name="webConfigJsCase"
        Inputs="@(FileToPublish)"
        Outputs="%(Identity).Dummy">
    <ItemGroup>
      <ContentFiltered Condition="$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::IsMatch('%(FileToPublish.Filename)%(FileToPublish.Extension)', 'web.config.js'))" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

I thought that `Inputs="@(ContentFiltered)"` will contain the lines that `DependsOnTargets="webConfigJsCase"` find.
But when i run it , i am getting this message: `Skipping target "CopyOldWebConfigJs" because it has no inputs.`

I know **for a fact** that the regex work, and it do find a filename_ext that equals `web.config.js` so it return  `True`
What do i do or understand wrong?

Comment: you should have copied the answer to said question *exactly*: you're missing a `Include="@(FileToPublish)" ` when defining `ContentFiltered `, without that you're just creating an empty item, hence the 'Skipping...' message

Comment: i tried that, and it didnt work- i removed it because, i thought it's not related, because he have ` Inputs="@(FileToPublish)"`

Comment: You cannot build itemgroups without using `Include`. Inputs has nothing to do with this, it's an attribute of Target. I tried it as well and it does work for me. So for example when FileToPublish contains "someweb.config.js" I get the message "web.config.js Case", as expected.

Answer (score 0):

In `<ItemGroup><Item/></ItemGroup>`, no change will be made to the `Item` item because no action was specified. If you want to add entries to the item, you must specify `Include=""`.

The [`<Item/>` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/msbuild/item-element-msbuild) describes the various attributes for item elements inside of an `<ItemGroup/>`. Note that at the top-level of an MSBuild file, directly under the `<Project/>` element, you would use the attributes `Include` and `Exclude` while in a `<Target/>` you would use the attributes `Include` and `Remove`. Not including any attributes at all is nonsensical and—as far as I know—no different than simply deleting the entire line. I am surprised MSBuild doesn’t throw an error or warning this is almost certainly a mistake and not intentional.

The `Inputs` and `Outputs` attributes on your `<Target Name="webConfigJsCase"/>` are unnecessary. In fact, they slow MSBuild down by making it loop over the target unnecessarily. You can filter just in the `<Item/>` like this:

```
<Target Name="webConfigJsCase">
  <ItemGroup>
    <ContentFiltered Condition="'%(FileToPublish.Filename)%(FileToPublish.Extension)' == 'web.config.js'" Include="@(FileToPublish)" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

Additionally, I assume that you intended your regular expression to match `web.config.js` but not match `webaconfigbjs`. You don’t need to use an advanced feature like Regular Expressions here because [MSBuild’s built-in condition operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-conditions) already support simple string comparison. If fixed the condition above to be more readable.